# How to find out WHEN a usb disk was removed?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, logging

I have got an external disk probably stolen from my computer at work. Is there any way to see in some system logs at what time this device was removed / unmounted? My operating system is Windows 7 (recently installed).

Answer (score 3):

Windows 7's Event Viewer does not log USB mount times. Instead, you can use the freeware called [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html).

> USBDeview is a small utility that
>   lists all USB devices that currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as
>   all USB devices that you previously
>   used.   For each USB device, exteneded
>   information is displayed: Device
>   name/description, device type, serial
>   number (for mass storage devices), the
>   date/time that device was added,
>   VendorID, ProductID, and more...
>   USBDeview also allows you to uninstall
>   USB devices that you previously used,
>   disconnect USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer,
>   as well as to disable and enable USB
>   devices.

[image]

Please try and let us know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I only see "Created Date". The "Last Plug/Unplug Date" has value "N/A" :-(. But at least I now have the serial number, which is also important. Thanks for that. Any further clues?

Comment: This is all I can suggest. Nice to know you got the S/N.