# Can I find out the time an iPod was (dis)connected?

Tags: windows-7, usb, logging, ipod

A friends iPod was taken while the iPod was connected to a computer and charging via USB. It would really help to find the person who took it if we knew what time the iPod was disconnected at. Is there anything on the computer that would keep track of this information?

Comment: I would check the system log in the event viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The windows event logs do not apparently record USB device connect/disconnect events. *See here: [How to find out WHEN a usb disk was removed?](https://superuser.com/questions/222305/how-to-find-out-when-a-usb-disk-was-removed)*

I tested this just now and it appear to be the case.

You can check for application errors, as iTunes may have written an error if it was open and trying to manage the iPod.

The link above provides a freeware solution, but it appears to only monitor changes going forward, as in when it is installed and running. Unfortunately, unless there is a log that iTunes writes, and iTunes was running, you may be out of luck trying to use system logs to find out when a device was removed.

Depending on the type of iPod, though, you may be able to look it up using Apple's Find My (Device) app.